# Are there any fruits that rely on dispersal of their seeds using excrement?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, fruit, seeds, germination

Are there any fruits that have seeds which can survive the digestive entirety of an animal's digestive system and remain germinable once passed on in animal excrement?

Perhaps this is the primary function of all seeded fruits and I'm just fundamentally unaware of the intended biological processes. If so, then why do poisonous seeded fruits exist?

Comment: Yes, many. A common example is the fruits containing capsaicin (e.g., hot peppers): this compound is an irritant to mammals but does not affect birds. This adaptation seems to have evolved to discourage consumption of the fruit by mammals, whose digestive systems damage the seeds, and to encourage consumption instead by birds, which distribute the seeds effectively.

Comment: Seeing as the main premise of your question is completely wrong (meaning that *loads* if not *all* fruit can survive the digestive system of an animal), I am voting to close as unclear. Please do some research (just glance through a wikipedia page or something) and ask something a bit more specific.

Comment: @terdon https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/voting-to-close-a-question-as-off-topic-because-it-is-based-on-a-faulty-presuppo

Comment: @canadianer yes, but my vote wasn't because the premise was wrong but because, given that the premise was wrong, the question is unclear. I mean, the question in the title can be answered by "Yes, most of them" but I don't think that's very interesting to the OP.

Comment: That's really kind of the point of having fruit in the first place. Why would the plant waste valuable nutrients just to feed animals? That doesn't mean that all fruit seeds survive the digestion of all different kinds of animals, of course, but the whole purpose of a fruit is to be eaten or carried (a lot rarer) by animals for dispersion.